# appear and disappear for a scroll depending on a conditional

Tags: java

everyone, excuse my language I speak Spanish and I use google translator

I have a question I can appear and disappear as one scroll lacelda depending on size or table for example when the cell arrives at a height of "300" scrolling appears visible, if not reach 300 not appear

How I can do that?

regards

Comment: I might be misunderstanding, but `JScrollPane`, but default, is configured to use the scroll bars "as required".  That is.  It will not display them unless the view exceeds the viewable area...

Answer (score 0):

There is a Swing class called JScrollPane. There are two functions called:

```
   scrollBar.getHorizontalScrollBar().getValue();
   scrollBar.getVerticalScrollBar().getValue();
```

You'll either need an event listener or a loop in a separate thread to check if the scroll bar is past a certain point.

The code to make it disappear is just:

```
scrollBar.setVisible(false)
```

The code to make it reappear:

```
scrollBar.setVisible(true);
scrollBar.validate();
scrollBar.repaint();
```